# HTTP: пользовательские заголовки

Tags: header, http

Есть ли в HTTP/1.1 (более ранние уже не актуальны, так?) какой-то формат пользовательских заголовков, то есть, тех, которые гарантированно будут игнорироваться клиентом и не приведут к каким-то конфликтам?

К примеру, в html5 ввели правило: атрибуты узлов, начинающиеся с `data-` будут игнорироваться и не будут никак задействованы движком — они пользовательские.

Есть ли аналог для хедеров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, аналог существует, для этого нужно добавить префикс X- к имени атрибута:

```
X-MY-ATTRIBUTE
```

Comment: Спасибо. Догадывался, но поиск "x-" по [RFC-2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) дал лишь упоминание о "x-gzip" и "x-compress". А вот на [вике](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#.D0.97.D0.B0.D0.B3.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B8) — да, так и написано:

 > Если не хватает существующих, то можно вводить свои. Традиционно к именам таких дополнительных заголовков добавляют префикс «X-» для избежания конфликта имён с возможно существующими.

Выглядит как «стандартом такого не предусмотрено, но придумывать можно».